# function scope in Python

Tags: python, scope

I just started learning Python today and was trying to call one function I defined from within another function.  The interpreter returned the error: NameError: global name 'isPrime' is not defined

Here is what my code looks like:

```
def split (value):
    x = 2
    halfOne, halfTwo = 0, 0
    if isPrime(value) == True:
        print (value)
        return
    else:
        while x < value:
            if value % x == 0:
                halfOne = value / x
                halfTwo = x
                split(halfOne)
                split(halfTwo)
            x += 1
def is_prime(value):
# some code
```

thank you for the help!

Answer (score 6):

Erm -- your function is called `is_prime`, not `isPrime`.

Comment: oh. I feel really dumb. Thank you!

Comment: We've all been there! :^) I find it helps to take error messages exactly literally to start with, looking for the simplest things first, and working outwards.

Comment: Please select any answer as correct answer to complete the workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the function `isPrime()` doesn't exist, just as the error message says? You do have one called `is_prime()` however; perhaps you could call that instead.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want `isPrime(value)` instead.

And you must define the function before it is invoked.

Comment: Just to be clear, the function only needs to be defined before it's used in a temporal sense, not in the sense of needing to be above it in the file.